# Apache HTTP/2 connections are not persistent

Tags: apache-2.4, http2

So I decided to implement HTTP/2 through Apache mod_http2. It was working fine, however every request, **except for those with under 1 sec between them**, is non-persistent. I am sure of this because as per the browser's network tools, the SSL connection is reinitialized every time:

[image]

Whereas, accessing the same page over HTTP/1.1 honors the server's keep-alive setting of 25 seconds and keeps the connection persistent:

[image]

Software running on the server:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4
Server MPM: event
PHP version: PHP 7.0.29 (cli)
PHP handler: PHP-FPM
```

So question is, why does HTTP/2 initiate a new SSL connection on each subsequent request? From what I read, the whole point of it should be of using persistent connections, whereas it does not. Or am I missing something here?

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be a bug to me and started in mod_http2 1.10.16 (released with Apache 2.4.30 - though a few issues with this meant it wasn't actually released until 2.4.33). Prior to that version it worked as you expected.

Have raised it with the mod_http2 author: https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/160

This was quickly fixed, and was subsequently included in the next Apache release (2.4.34 released on 16th July 2018).

Comment: Ah, finally. After hours & hours of debugging finally I can rest that I'm not crazy. Thank you. Hopefully we'll see a fix in the next release.

Comment: Apache 2.4.34 was released today which includes this fix.